# asp.net mvc datetime didn't display their value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, razor

I have an asp.net mvc 4 project and in my view model have a datetime control. And into my controller income datetime property format: 09/20/2013 12:00:00 AM and when I try to send it into my view via ViewBag.DateTime and try to display it in my View it didn't display my value in calendar format, just display mm/dd/yyyy and I need to select value from calendar. Here is my code:

**Model**

```
[Display(Name = "Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime DateValue { get; set; }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Date(DateTime? DateValue)
{
    if (ExamsDate != null)//ExamsDate have a value and it's sending into view
    {
       ViewBag.DateValue = DateValue;
    }
    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateValue):<br/>
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateValue) //Here instead of 09/20/2013 display mm/dd/yyyy
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateValue)
```

Anybody know where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this attribute to your model:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
```

However if you want an actual calendar control, you'll need to use something like jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing basic thing that you need to access nullable field value like this

```
Datevalue.value instead of just Datevalue and use date time formatting
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your EditorFor to TextBoxFor

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateValue, new { @Value = Model.DateValue.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")})
```